# Please explain this PHP code/syntax related to building forum pages

Tags: php

OK so i am trying to build a forum from scratch and i realize the pages corresponding to topics will have to be generated dynamically somehow. I'm looking at a forum i frequently visit and I would like someone to explain the PHP syntax/code for the flow that I see as I have never seen the "something.php?x=something" type of structure before.

OK so user first visits site and the page says

```
http://forumname.com/index.php?sid=someLongSetOfChars
```

(im guessing this is a session id?...what is the "?" where can i learn about it)

clicking login takes you to

```
forumname.com/ucp.php?mode=login (what is mode? how do i know to do this?)
```

after logging in successfully you get

```
forumname.com/index.php?sid=otherLongSetofChars
```

this page has the various forums in different categories.

Clicking on one of the categories gives:

```
http://forumname.com/viewforum.php?f=1
```

Clicking on one of the topics gives:

```
http://forumname.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=192053
```

All these things sort of make sense to me (semantically) but I am wondering how they actually work and how to implement them. What variables would I have to define and where and are these pages created and stored on my server?

Thanks

Comment: The manual explains some of that http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php (also see comments) and in http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php

Comment: Since you don't seem to have any background in PHP at all, I suggest you start with this tutorial and familiarize yourself first : http://devzone.zend.com/article/627

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
http://forumname.com/index.php?sid=someLongSetOfChars
```

You're right. Everything after the `?` are so called GET parameters. They consist of a parameter name and value. The name here is `sid` and its value is the session ID. The value can be accessed in the PHP file `index.php`.

```
forumname.com/ucp.php?mode=login
```

Mode is another GET parameter. Its value is `login`. I am guessing the `ucp.php` file looks for the `mode` parameter and sees that you want to login. The script will show you the login page.

```
forumname.com/index.php?sid=otherLongSetofChars
```

The `index.php` script knows through your session ID that you are logged in successfully. Because of this you can see all the forums.

```
http://forumname.com/viewforum.php?f=1
http://forumname.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=192053
```

There will be PHP scripts called `viewforum.php` and `viewtopic.php` which take the parameter `f` (for forum) and `t` (for topic). Based on the IDs of forum and topic the PHP scripts will show you the right topics/forums.

To summarize, it all boils down to parsing parameters sent through GET (those you can see in the URL). There is another type called POST parameter. Those are sent, for example, when you log in, but "in the background" and not through the URL. They exist because you wouldn't want to have your password in cleartext in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about the session id.  You can read more about session_id passing [here](http://php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php).  The ? marks the start of the query_string and is not related to the session ID.  The query string consists of all the variables that are available to the server via the URL.  In PHP, these are accessible via the $_GET super global (this means that it is predefined.)

You can see all the defined query string variables by doing:

```
print_r($_GET);
```

Mode is simply a variable that the creators of the forum have defined.  I am assuming that ucp stands for user control panel and in their ucp.php file, they will have some code that looks like:

```
$mode = $_GET['mode'];
if ($mode == "login")
{
    //login
}
elseif ($mode == "logout")
{
    //logout
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the key/value pairs after the ? in the url correspond to key/value pairs in the superglobal associative array $_GET in PHP. you can make entries in it with:

```
$_GET[key]="value"
```

and you can retrieve values from it with:

```
$_GET[key]
```

check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php for more info!

Andy

Answer (score 0):

It's called a "query string", representing HTTP GET parameters.

[Here's what it means to HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), and [here's how to use it](http://ditio.net/2008/06/12/php-query-string/) in [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

Answer (score -3):

This may help:
http://w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp

The "?" in the URL denotes the rest of the URL are GET variables. Get variables are in the form of  {{key}}={{value}} and seperated by &s.

I'm not going to pretend I know the database structure or PHP structure of your forum but here is an example of how to get use the GET variables in your last URL:

```
<?php

$f = $_GET['f'];
$t = $_GET['t'];

//Now use $f and $t to find corresponding IDs in forum's database

....

?>
```

This is a naive example and you'll want to do some input sanitation to avoid XSS attacks and attempts at URL hacking. the `$f` variable most likely corresponds to the ID of the row in the "forum" table whereas the `$t` variable most likely corresponds ot the ID of the row in the "topics" table in the forums database. Use these variables to pull the correct information from the database and generate the appropriate page.

Comment: Please refrain from linking to w3schools.  They teach bad habits.  See: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: yeah, never ever mention w3schools in SO, they vote you down down down down down and down... it's kind of forbidden word here I guess.

Comment: Unfortunately I found out the hard way... I never thought highly of their example code but then again I thought it was geared more towards showing basic code syntax on how to accomplish simple tasks for newcomers. I can definitely see why a programming community such as SO would abhor such a site. My apologies. It won't happen again, I promise.

Comment: yeah, so did I... don't apologies, we have not done anything wrong.